# Javascript not updating array

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a simple app in javaScript. There is a list of cats and when I click on any element in list, it displays an image and when I click on that image, it increases the count property of cat obj.

After Clicking on admin button, when I am trying update any fields on cat object, it is getting reinitialized to zero value.

HTML code

```
<ul id="list">
</ul>
<div id="cat">
    <h2 id="cat-name"></h2>
    <div id="cat-count"></div>
    <img id="cat-img" src="">
    <button id="admin" class="hide">Admin</button>
    <form id="form" class="hide">
        <input type="text" id="curr-cat-name"/>
        <input type="text" id="curr-cat-url"/>
        <input type="text" id="curr-cat-count"/>
        <button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button id="save">Save</button>
    </form>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cat.js"></script>
```

Javascript

```
(function(){

    var model = {
        currentCat : null,
        init: function() {
            this.cats = [
            {
                "name" : "Cat 1",
                "src"  : "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/f0/26/05/f0260599e1251c67eefca31c02a19a81.jpg",
                "count" : 0
            },{
                "name" : "Cat 2",
                "src"  : "https://dq25e8j0im0tm.cloudfront.net/images/public/search/Search_Tab_Cat_395x335-3.png",
                "count" : 0
            },{
                "name" : "Cat 3",
                "src"  : "http://www.pak101.com/funnypictures/Animals/2012/8/2/the_monopoly_cat_vbgkd_Pak101(dot)com.jpg",
                "count" : 0

            }, {

                "name" : "Cat 4",
                "src"  : "https://files.graphiq.com/stories/t2/tiny_cat_12573_8950.jpg",
                "count" : 0

            }, {

                "name" : "Cat 5",
                "src"  : "http://cdn-img.health.com/sites/default/files/styles/400x400/public/styles/400x400/public/styles/main/public/how-take-care-cat-400x400.jpg?itok=ta2kPB58",
                "count" : 0

            }
            ];
        },

        getAllCats: function() {
            console.log(this.cats);
            return this.cats;
        },

        updateCat: function(cat) {
            model.currentCat.name = cat.name;
            model.currentCat.count = parseInt(cat.count);
            model.currentCat.src = cat.src;
            console.log(model.getAllCats);
        }
    }

    var octopus = {
        init: function() {

            model.init();
            model.currentCat = model.getAllCats[0];
            view.init();
        },

        getCats: function() {
            return model.getAllCats();

        },

        setCurrentCat: function(cat) {
            console.log(cat);
            model.currentCat = cat;
        },

        modifyCat : function(obj) {
            model.updateCat(obj);
        },

        incrementCounter: function() {
            model.currentCat.count++;
            view.renderCat();
        },

        getCurrentCat: function() {
            return model.currentCat;
        }
    }

    var view = {
        init: function() {
            this.list = document.getElementById("list");
            this.catImg = document.getElementById("cat-img");
            this.catName = document.getElementById("cat-name");
            this.catCount = document.getElementById("cat-count");
            this.adminBtn = document.getElementById("admin");


            this.adminBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
                view.renderForm();
            });

            this.catImg.addEventListener('click', function(){
                octopus.incrementCounter();
            });

        // render this view (update the DOM elements with the right values)
        view.renderList();
    },

    renderList: function() {
        var catLis = document.getElementById("list");
        octopus.getCats().forEach(function(cat){
            var elem = document.createElement("li");
            elem.textContent = cat.name; 
            elem.addEventListener('click', (function(catCopy){
                return function(){
                    octopus.setCurrentCat(catCopy);
                    view.renderCat();
                };
            })(cat));

            this.list.appendChild(elem);

        });


    },

    renderCat: function() {
        var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
        this.catCount.textContent = currentCat.count;
        this.catName.textContent = currentCat.name;
        this.catImg.src = currentCat.src;
        this.adminBtn.classList.remove("hide");
        this.adminBtn.classList.add("show");

    },

    renderForm: function() {
        var currentCat = octopus.getCurrentCat();
        this.form = document.getElementById("form");
        this.form.classList.remove("hide");
        this.form.classList.add("show");
        this.catFormImg = document.getElementById("curr-cat-url");
        this.catFormName = document.getElementById("curr-cat-name");
        this.catFormCount = document.getElementById("curr-cat-count");
        this.catFormCount.value = currentCat.count;
        this.catFormName.value = currentCat.name;
        this.catFormImg.value = currentCat.src;
        this.cancelBtn = document.getElementById("cancel");
        this.saveBtn = document.getElementById("save");


        this.saveBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(view);
            octopus.modifyCat({
                name: document.getElementById("curr-cat-name").value,
                count: document.getElementById("curr-cat-count").value,
                src: document.getElementById("curr-cat-url").value
            });
            /*this.form.classList.remove("show");
            this.form.classList.add("hide");
            view.adminBtn.classList.remove("show");
            view.adminBtn.classList.add("hide");*/
        });

        this.cancelBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
            this.form.classList.remove("show");
            this.form.classList.add("hide");
            view.adminBtn.classList.remove("show");
            view.adminBtn.classList.add("hide");
        });



    }


}

octopus.init();

})();
```

CSS

```
#result {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-weight: medium;
    font-size: 34px;
}

img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.show {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: You never use `catLis`.

Comment: Yes, I am using this.list in place of catLis

Comment: You are probably forgetting to do the `e.preventDefault()` when clicking on the buttons (as they are part of a form, they will submit the form, resetting your application). If I add `type="button"` to both save & cancel buttons, it works almost perfect (the click count doesn't update to the value I set in the textbox), however when switching cats and coming back it's working flawlesly

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks for the suggestion, it is working perfect now.

Comment: If you are not going to be actually submitting the form data anywhere, and only want to have interactivity, don't add the `form` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click the save button your `<form>` is triggered which causes the browser to reload the page. Look at your browser tab. It's hardly recognizable because it happens so fast. In order to prevent the browser from reloading you have at least two options.

1. Don't use a form. Just put your input elements in a div or something.
2. The function that is called on 'click' takes an event. This `event` is the click. You can prevent the page to reload with `event.preventDefault()`.

See comment by @Icepickle for a couple of more possibilities.

Comment: A third option would be add `type="button"` to the buttons ;) or use `<input type="button" value="save" />` :) Lots more than 2 options ;)